# Wordpress Stylesheet is missing on every theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

Hi there After installation of wordpress on my hosting I try to upload Divi theme after installation when I clicked on Activate it gives me an error **Stylesheet is Missing**.
In-fact whenever i try to Activate default theme like twenty sixteen , twenty seventeen, it gives me same error **Stylesheet is Missing**.
I reinstall wordpress and again the same issue.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please make sure that you want to install Divi theme and not Divi builder plugin
First of all please download the Divi theme package.zip file then try to install the theme from Appearance >  Theme > add new > upload your theme package.zip file from here.
Actually some people are getting confused while trying to install Divi theme cause of,
Elegant theme also comes with Divi builder plugin and that's why misconception is created.
I'm suggestion you to  do it from scratch then check

Comment: yes i confirm this. but problem is not divi theme. it gives me same error Stylesheet is Missing whenever i try to Activate default theme in wordpress